# Beginner in need of bash assistance

Tags: linux, bash, shell, android-ndk

I am currently editing a script so that some of the static values are hardcoded in since I will be the only one using it. That values that are taken are as follows:

```
set -x
ANDROID_NDK="$1"
NDK_TOOLCHAIN="$2"
ANDROID_ABI="$3"
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_COMPILER_VERSION="$4"
ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL="$5"
PREFIX="$6"
```

I want to change `ANDROID_NDK="$1"` to a path value. I tried input the path so it became `ANDROID_NDK="path/to/ndk/"` but that gives errors. I saw where I need to use `PATH=` but how can I set the variable `ANDROID_NDK` to the path?

Would it be `PATH=$ANDROID_NDK:path/to/ndk` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PATH=$PATH:path/to/ndk
```

You want to preserve the old PATH value.  That's where your programs live.

You also say you want to set the NDK variable to what is currently in path.  In which case it's...

ANDROID_NDK=$PATH:path/to/ndk

Comment: Will using this mess up where the script calls in $PATH? Such as PATH=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT:$PATH?

Comment: The PATH variable is simply where your terminal looks for executable files with the name you type into the bash line.  If you type "gcc" there is an executable file called "gcc" somewhere in one of your path directories.  The semicolon is a delimiter effectively saying AND.  All you're doing in what I provided is adding your path-to-ndk as an extra directory to look for a program.